# Expanded root volume but tmpfs and devtmpfs is limited

Tags: filesystems, linux-kernel, amazon-ec2, tmpfs, amazon-linux

I have expanded root volume in my Amazon ec2 machine (Amazon Linux 2) but the space in `tmpfs` and `devtempfs` is still limited.

Here is what output of `df -h` command looks like:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           7.9G  468K  7.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda1      100G  8.1G   92G   9% /
/dev/xvdb        60G  4.3G   56G   8% /data
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
```

What's the safest and quick way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It says *Used: 0* - which means that it's not *full* but instead that it's *empty*.
2. `tmpfs` and `devtmpfs` are memory-based filesystems, they are limited by the amount of available RAM, not by the available disk space. Typically they can consume up to 50% of the RAM so I assume that your EC2 instance has 16GB RAM.
3. Why do you need more space in `tmpfs` or `devtmpfs`?

   It's not really intended for storing large amounts of data. Also note that the contents will be wiped when you reboot the machine.